# Android image resizing error

Tags: android, css, imageview, android-appwidget

I'm working on a widget here, but I got stuck in this part. The widget will show the battery level, with a image in background. The problem is that the image gets smaller than the original size, and overlay the text(the battery level).

Here the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"  
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:gravity="center" >  
           <LinearLayout   
             android:id="@+id/layout"  
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
             android:layout_margin="10dip"  
             android:gravity="center_vertical"  
             android:orientation="vertical"  
             android:paddingTop="0dip" >  

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/widget_text"
                 style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                 android:layout_width="100sp"
                 android:layout_height="0sp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                 android:text="@string/battery_level"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:textSize="24sp" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
               android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
               android:layout_weight="100">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="50"
                   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                   android:contentDescription="@string/content"
                   android:paddingRight="5dip"
                   android:scaleType="fitXY"
                   android:src="@drawable/widget_base" />

               </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas of how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should move the first LinearLayout (includes TextView) after the second LinearLayout to bring the text to front.
Also there are some mistakes in your design and it's better to add a complete picture about what you want.
Anyway you can use this ;-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_base" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/battery_level"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use an image about 128x48 pixel like [this](http://i1290.photobucket.com/albums/b531/zhonos/widget_base_zps30253858.png)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, now the text shows above the picture:) but the picture still too small:( .. here take a look:
http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w522/Martinho_Alexandre/pic1_zpsde7b93dd.png
I'm getting this, but i want something like this:
http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w522/Martinho_Alexandre/pic2_zps9e9fb341.png

Comment: Edited. And I think it's better to use "%" when use set text. for example myTextView.setText(battery_level + " %");

Comment: Ahh almost there, the image is bigger now, and the text appears above it :) but still small and now it goes to the bottom of the screen :( take a look: http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w522/Martinho_Alexandre/pic1_zpsc8566ad4.png
After some time I find a way to put in the correct place, but I can't resize the image correctly, and remove that blur :\ anyway, thanks for helping!